# Why, when we are testing if the fragment is visible, do we test if the fragment is not null?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Why, when we are testing if the fragment is visible, do we test if the fragment is not null?

```
FragmentB f2 = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmenrById(R.id.fragB);

if(f2 != null && f2.isVisible())
{
 // landscape

}else
{
   //portrait

}
```

Comment: Check through `fragment.getUserVisibleHint()`

Comment: my question is why we test if the fragment != null when we test if the fragment is visible

Comment: Err, in case the fragment is, err, null? If it can't be, don't test it. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your Fragment code .

```
@Override  
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {  
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);  
    if (isVisibleToUser) {  
        // visible
    } else {  
        // invisible 
    }  
}
```

And do like this .

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        // Visible
    } else {
        // Invisible
    }
}
```

Comment: @hackour try this solution

Comment: @AndroCoderHelper Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When starting your Fragment, add a tag to it like this:

```
MyFragmentClass myFragment = new MyFragmentClass();
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

ft.replace(R.id.main_container, myFragment, "MY_FRAG");
```

Then you wish to see if it is visible just to this:

```
MyFragmentClass test = (MyFragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAG");

if (test != null && test.isVisible()) {
  //DO STUFF
} 
else {
  //Whatever
}
```

Comment: `if` block never becomes true until you do inter-thread communication just above `if` block. Another thread from Fragment should tell the thread that Fragment's onStart() completed. After you receive this message then you can have `if` block.

Comment: Normally I use this and it has worked but I probably should take this into consideration. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a particular fragment is visible or not is guaranteed only by that fragment. If fragment wants another component about it, it should do inter-thread communication.

Fragments are independent dynamic components like threads of OS. Fragments become visible after they complete `onStart()` callback body.

1) You can check if the fragment is visible inside Fragment's class after it completes `onStart()` body. For instance, you can check on

```
onClickofView() { //check your above written code here
/*Note: Since you are inside the fragment, you don't need to check if the fragment is null or not? */
}
```

2) If you want to check a particular fragment is null or not from outer space (from another fragment or activity), you need to do inter-thread communication. For this, you use **notifying worker thread** inside your fragment just after you complete `onStart()`. Another thread from anywhere gets that message and can check if the fragment is visible or not? Another thread can be in Activity where you started so many fragments asynchronously using **`FragmentManager.beginTransaction()`**.